# Если пример пространный, можно ли после "например" или "к примеру "ставить точку?

Tags: пунктуация

Подзабыла правило, напомните, пожалуйста!

> Вот например: некий персонаж по имени Франсуа Андре родился в забытой
>   богом французской деревеньке недалеко от города Леона и, следуя
>   законам жанра, ему было уготовано стать ни больше ни меньше как
>   земледельцем, а при счастливом стечении обстоятельств, быть может,
>   виноделом. В любом случае – крестьянином. Но он решает перебраться в
>   Париж, в конце – теперь уже позапрошлого – столетия. и начинает
>   испытывать судьбу.

Есть ещё какие-либо замечания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно справочнику Розенталя:

> Точка ставится в конце предложения, вводящего в дальнейшее развернутое изложение: Вот этот рассказ. (Пауст.) [дальше следует рассказ]; [...]; Новый станок имеет такое устройство. [дальше — пространное описание].

В рассматриваемом случае я бы заменил "вот например" на, скажем, "вот типичный пример" или "вот один из примеров" и поставил точку. Двоеточие перед таким развёрнутым повествованием вряд ли уместно.

Comment: А мне где пятёрка? Проблема в том, что у меня особые отношения с нумерологмей...

Comment: * с нумерологией. ))) Не люблю чётных.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Постараюсь не забывать :) Вообще, я пытаюсь отвечать только на те вопросы, в которых мне интересно разбираться. Следовательно, это уже означает, что вопрос мне понравился.